# Choosing the right Jasypt encryptor implementation for passing encrypted data via HTTP

Tags: jasypt

My application manipulates database identifiers. I wish to hide those values from my users.

I am looking for a way to encrypt those identifiers when they are passed on from the server-side to the client-side and decrypt them when they are passed the other way round.

For your information the **unencrypted identifiers are integers** (java longs). I have a further requirement to **pass the encrypted identifiers via HTTP**. Furthermore, the encrypted values do not necessarily need to be integers.

I currently use the Jasypt `StandardPBEBigIntegerEncryptor` with a password but I am getting:

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
```

Can anyone please recommend me an appropriate implementation of `xxEncryptor` from the numerous Jasypt classes given my requirements?

**edit**: I am actually just trying to encrypt a **positive java long** into another **positive java long**. The data happens to be a JPA entity ID:

```
private Long id;
```

I then use a Json serializer (`JsonSerializer<Long>`) in order to encrypt the data sent over from the REST endpoint to the javascript client and a Json deserializer (`JsonDeserializer<Long>`) in order to decrypt the data that the javascript client sends over to the REST endpoint.

Comment: EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException is a very general exception, doesn't explain the problem. maybe, providing a minimal example can help answer your question.

Comment: if you're encrypting integers with a password, why can't you just XOR them with password bytes?

Comment: Hi. Regarding your first comment there is no more specific exception in the stacktrace unfortunately.

Comment: Regarding your second comment I am very interested in the solution you suggest. Can you please provide sample code or pointers?

Comment: sure, post your snippet and i'll modify it.

Comment: Hi @ilj, I have edited my post by providing additional information. As explained the data encrypted/decrypted is just a positive java long. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    static Random r = new Random();

    static class Data {
        long id = r.nextLong();

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data{" + "id=" + id + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            data.add(new Data());
        }

        final String password = "don't you ever tell them";

        byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes();
        long[] passwordLongs = new long[passwordBytes.length / 8];

        for (int i = 0; i < passwordLongs.length; i++) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
            byte[] chunk = new byte[Long.BYTES];
            System.arraycopy(passwordBytes, i*Long.BYTES, chunk, 0, Long.BYTES);
            buffer.put(chunk);
            buffer.flip();//need flip
            passwordLongs[i] = buffer.getLong();
        }

        System.out.println(data);

        ListIterator<Data> encryptIterator = data.listIterator();
        while (encryptIterator.hasNext()) {
            Data next = encryptIterator.next();
            next.id = next.id ^ passwordLongs[(encryptIterator.nextIndex()-1) % passwordLongs.length];
        }

        System.out.println(data);

        ListIterator<Data> decryptIterator = data.listIterator();
        while (decryptIterator.hasNext()) {
            Data next = decryptIterator.next();
            next.id = next.id ^ passwordLongs[(decryptIterator.nextIndex()-1) % passwordLongs.length];
        }

        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Can I please ask one last little favor from you? Can you please briefly explain the cryptography part of your code? Especially: what does the for loop does from a cryptography point of view? What about the the second line of the encrypt/decrypt while loops?

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that you use actual BigIntegers, not Java long.

```
myEncryptor.encrypt(new BigInteger(myId));
```

If you are still having problems using BigIntegers, or you can't use them directly because of difficult entity configuration, etc., you can convert your IDs to strings and encrypt using a StandardPBEStringEncryptor.

Lastly, check to ensure that if you are passing these in HTTP requests, you are not putting them in the query string of a GET request. Jasypt will base64 encode things, and that includes some character like "=" that don't work in URLs. When passed back, they need to go in a POST, or in headers.

A side note: depending on your threat model, you may want to encrypt with something other than a set password. Maybe use the session key as the password. Otherwise users might not *know* the actual key, but will still be able to copy out the encrypted values and reuse them in other contexts that you don't intend.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately the data ends up in query strings... Any other idea? Otherwise your side note is very interesting and worth taking into account!